# Build fails because of autogenerated obj/debug files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a simple xamarin forms application which was working perfectly until it started giving the following error out of the blue (I haven't made any changes to the project that I know of since the last time it worked.)

[image]

along with the way too often met error

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in current context

I tried cleaning, rebuilding, restarting, deleting cache but I keep getting the same error. 
Anything else I can do to get rid of this? Or any idea why this might be happening or how I can avoid it?

I am using VS 15.5.6

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing any `}` .. you can try once to build it in realease mode and see what happens.

Comment: It looks like there's probably a typo in TablconsPage.xaml that is making it through the XAML -> C# compiler, then causing the C# compilation to break.

Comment: Install XAML styler extension of visual studio. It might help with finding mistype in xaml